# “Add to project list” is grayed out in Qt Project Management dialog

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ide

I'm trying to add a new statically linked library to a Qt-based application.

I used this guide: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

But when I get to step 4, which says "In the Add to project list, select a project. For example, myapp", I'm unable to do this because the Add to project list is disabled (gray) in the Project Management dialog.

What is required for Qt Creator to recognize other projects at this point, such that they appear in the list (which would then, presumably, no longer be disabled)?

I'm working on Linux/GNU, on a PC machine.

Answer (score 2):

See the post here: http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-creator/2010-December/008166.html

Your "library" project and your "application" project both need to be part of a "Subdirs" project.

First, create a Subdirs project, which will contain all the individual projects for your overall project (this is like a "Solution" in Visual Studio).

Then, create your library project, by right-clicking the "subdirs" project, and selecting "New Subproject...", and then follow the instructions from the QtCreator docs, and the overall project should be available in the drop-down.

Finally (assuming you want to create a dependency from an application to your library), create  your application project as a sub-project of the overall project, and then you can add your library project as an "internal library" of your application project.